# MongoDB - Find in nested arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

My goal is to:

1. Get all the documents with `status=true`.
2. And return only objects with `active=true` in the `life` array.

Below is what my MongoDB documents look like:

```
{
    "name": "justine",
    "life" : [ 
        {
            "status" : true,
            "service" : [ 
                {
                    "partner" : "pat 1",
                    "active" : true,
                }, 
                {
                    "partner" : "pat 2",
                    "active" : false
                }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "okumu",
    "life" : [ 
        {
            "status" : true,
            "service" : [ 
                {
                    "partner" : "pat 1",
                    "active" : true,
                }, 
                {
                    "partner" : "pat 2",
                    "active" : true
                }
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "name": "justine",
    "life" : [ 
        {
            "status" : true,
            "service" : [ 
                {
                    "partner" : "pat 1",
                    "active" : true,
                }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "okumu",
    "life" : [ 
        {
            "status" : true,
            "service" : [ 
                {
                    "partner" : "pat 1",
                    "active" : true,
                }, 
                {
                    "partner" : "pat 2",
                    "active" : true
                }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what I did:

```js
await Users.find({ life: { $elemMatch: { status: true, life: { $elemMatch: { active: false } } } }});
```

This is working well for the first condition, in case the second condition is not met, the entire object is not returned, however, if it's met, even the `active=false` objects are returned.

I'll be grateful if you can help me out, am not a MongoDB expert.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is complex (possible not doable) with the `.find()` query.

You should use `.aggregate()` query.

1. `$match` - Filter document with `life.status` is `true`.
2. `$project` -

   2.1 `$filter` - Filter the document with `status` is `true` in `life` array document.

   2.1.1 `$map` - Merge the `life` document with the Result *2.1.1.1*.

   2.1.1.1 `$filter` - The inner `$filter` operator to filter the document with `active` is `true` for `service` document in `service` array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "life.status": true
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      life: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$life",
              "in": {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$this",
                  {
                    "service": {
                      "$filter": {
                        "input": "$$this.service",
                        "as": "service",
                        "cond": {
                          $eq: [
                            "$$service.active",
                            true
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          as: "life",
          "cond": {
            $eq: [
              "$$life.status",
              true
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TMU8qAFDhFO)

Comment: I still wonder why your profile photo looks like an error file. Maybe it's bug from SO ?

Comment: Haha, my profile was linked with Facebook. And due to the Facebook account no longer being accessible, it shows a broken file.

Comment: Oh okay, now I get it ! Maybe SO should stored the photo in it's own database instead of stored only the link. I like your answer and I up vote it.